# Using Parceble to communicate between activities

Tags: android

So I am trying to pass my object from one activity to another using `Parceble` provided in android as it is the right thing to use in this case.

This is my Bean Class which I have `serialized` by implementing `Parceble`

**Customer.class**

```
public class Customer implements Parcelable {

    int a;
    String name;

    public Customer(int ab , String n) {
    this.a=ab;
    this.name=n;
    }

    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public Customer(Parcel in) {
         a= in.readInt();   
         name= in.readString();
        //readFromParcel(in);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeInt(a);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Customer> CREATOR= new Parcelable.Creator<Customer>() {

        @Override
        public Customer createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new Customer(source);
        }

        @Override
        public Customer[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Customer[size];
        }
    };


    private void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {

        a= in.readInt();    
        name= in.readString();
   }
}
```

**MainActivity.class**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button b;
    Customer c;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        c=new Customer(33,"nn");

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,CustomActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("myobj", c);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**CustomActivity.class**

```
public class CustomActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent it=getIntent();
        Customer c=(Customer)it.getParcelableExtra("myobj");

        System.out.println("and object is "+c.getA()+"/"+c.getName());
    }
}
```

**And this is my output in Logcat:**

```
05-15 12:02:56.014: I/System.out(25581): and object is 2/null
```

Comment: It's `Parcelable`, not *Parceble*.

Comment: @adrianp thanks for the typo I didn't paste it from code , just wrote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your `readFromParcel` method. The rule is that "***the sequence of members must be same while writing or reading members of Parcelable objects***"

So you have to change `readFromParcel(Parcel in)` from

```
private void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {    
        a= in.readInt();    
        name= in.readString();
   }
```

to

```
private void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {              
        name= in.readString();
       a= in.readInt();  
   }
```

Because your `writeToParcel(..)` writes `name` first and then `a`.

[PARCELABLE INTERFACE OVERVIEW](http://blog.logicexception.com/2012/09/a-parcelable-tutorial-for-android.html) can be a good reference for you.

Comment: Ok , so its the order of `writeToParcel` that I have to maintain.